# Parallel ForEach - Sucessive calls last longer

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, webclient, dispose, parallel.foreach

I have a function that basically iterates in a parallel kind of way to parallelize the following process:

1. Fetch a web page
2. Parse html code
3. Return results and add to a result collection

The problem is it takes about 5 minutes to run the first time and 40 minutes the second time. The input collection is not changed therefore the time to run should be very similar. Any idea?

I have included the GetPrices(int). The second time this is run, it starts with 0 connections in netstat (so there is none from the first time eating up available connections) but it only grows to 5 connections (as opposed to 30 in the first run).

Also, in your opinion does the return collection needs to be locked?

```
    public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, double>> GetPrices(List<int> IDs)
    {
        Stopwatch web_time = new Stopwatch(), regex_time = new Stopwatch();
        Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, double>> ret = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, double>>();
        int aux_bkp = ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit;
        ParallelOptions pOptions = new ParallelOptions();

        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 30;

        pOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 35;
        Parallel.ForEach(IDs, pOptions, ID=>
            {
                Dictionary<int, double> aux = GetPrices(ID);

                lock (ret)
                {
                    ret.Add(ID, new Dictionary<int, double>());
                    foreach (int kID in aux.Keys)
                    {
                        ret[mktID].Add(kID , aux[kID ]);
                    }
                }

            });

        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = aux_bkp;

        return ret;
    }
    public static Dictionary<int, double> GetPrices(int ID)
    {
        Stopwatch web_time = new Stopwatch(), regex_time = new Stopwatch();
        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
        string resp;
        Dictionary<int, double> ret = new Dictionary<int, double>();
        bool success = false;
        int retries = 0;

        web_time.Start();
        while (!success)
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Get HTML: ({1}) - ({0})", url, ID));

                resp = webclient.DownloadString(url);
                success = true;
                web_time.Stop();

                regex_time.Start();


                regex_time.Start();

                ret = ProcessHTML(resp, ID);
                regex_time.Stop();

            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {

                System.Net.HttpWebResponse aux;

                aux = e.Response as System.Net.HttpWebResponse;
                if (aux == null || aux.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    success = false;
                    retries++;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(new System.Random().Next(5000));
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HTTP Error - " + e.ToString());
                }
                else if (aux != null || aux.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    success = true;
                }


            }

        regex_time.Stop();
        return ret;
        }
```

Comment: The problem is most likely with `GetPrices`. Perhaps you are not closing connections properly.

Comment: you should make locked code as small as possible the loop in it is not required to be there you can create dictionary and fill it outside of lock and lock only `ret.Add(kID,innerDictionary)`

Comment: But the entire cycle lasts 5 min first and 40 min in the second time. In that case (connections not closing) even the first time would take longer correct?

Comment: @HugoVarandas If the first time you're using 35 connections but the second time most of them are still busy because they weren't closed properly, you might only be effectively using a handful of them, explaining the difference. Either you way you need to show `GetPrices`.

Comment: Much better to use a ConcurrentDictionary rather than locking as the lock will be interfering with the effectiveness of the parallelism - but as @Rotem pointed out it wouldn't explain the slowdown

Comment: Maybe code from `GetPrices(int)` would help us to help you.

Comment: not related to the slowdown but you can (potentially) speed the loop up. 

`ret.Add(ID, new Dictionary<int, double>());
     ICollection<KeyValuePair<int,doublc>> col = ret[mktID]; 
     foreach (var k in aux)
     {
        col.Add(k);
     }`

Comment: You can do this without locking _at all_ if you do e.g. `var ret = IDs.ToDictionary(i => i, i => new Dictionary<int, double>());` Your parallelization is trying to speed up `GetPrices` - setting up the dictionary in one go should be negligible, and _reading_ the dictionary is thread-safe.

Comment: I have included the GetPrices(int). The second time this is run, it starts with 0 connections in netstat (so there is none from the first time eating up available connections) but it only grows to 5 connections (as opposed to 30 in the first run).